# How to have left side equal to right side?

Tags: html, css

I have html structure like this:

```css
nav{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:40px;
  list-style-type:none;
}
header,.body{
  display:inline-block;
}
header{
  height:30px;
  background:blue;
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
.body{
  background:red;
 width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
       <li>Test 1</li>
       <li>Test 1</li>
       <li>Test 1</li>
       <li>Test 1</li>
       <li>Test 1</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="body">
      <h3>something</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

What i want is that my `<div class="body"></div>` is going to the end of nav with height. So if i have 100 li , header will always have same height of 30px, but body with red background will go to the end of nav. they will have same height.
Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "to the end of nav with height"?

Comment: can you explain what you need?

Comment: your question is very unclear. Please be more specific. Also your HTML structure is not very logical . You already have a default `body` tag , i suggest you use `.content` instead of body . Also `nav` is usually inside of header .

Comment: nav is on left side , and div is on right side... so nav have because of multiple li some height and i want that body on right side have same height

Comment: @MihaT i fixed...i want that red backaground is as same as nav height

Comment: and `header` ? where should it be ? because now it's over the nav

Comment: i want that is header on right side as <div class="body">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `header` and `content` ( i changed the class `body` to `content` so you don't confuse it with the default `body` tag ) inside a wrapper ( i named it `contentWrapper` ) and use `flexBox` on the `wrapper`

See below

The height of the `content` ( red space ) is calculated with `calc(100% - 30px)` where `100%` is the entire height of the column and `30px` is the height of the `header`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  width: auto;
  background: green;
}

header {
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  height: calc(100% - 30px)
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="contentWrapper">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>something</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the css selector `.body`, with which you can select a class named 'body', with de css selector `body`, which selects the entire body of the DOM.

Change your css to:

```
nav{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
}
header,.body{
  display:inline-block;
}
header{
  height:30px;
  background:blue;
}
.body{
 background:red;
}
```

As *Mihai T* is saying as well, I suggest you change the class name of your `div` to something else than `body`, because it can cause confusion.

Comment: i dont want fixed size

Comment: Really, please make yourself clear. Fixed size? On what?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper>div>* {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
}

.body {
  background: red;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
      <li>Test 1</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="body">
      <h3>something</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want to li be in one row

Comment: yes but i want that is header and something one bellow another, and that div have height as nav on left side